# What are "abstract semantics" and "actual semantics"?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

This sentense is found in N1570(5.1.2.3-8), the final draft of C11:

> More stringent correspondences between abstract and actual semantics may be defined by each implementation.

It seems that no definitions have been given on "abstract and actual semantics".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The draft explains how execution should occurs, and this description is based on the C abstract machine, so it defines an *abstract semantic*. But it is possible to define an implementation of this draft that may differ from this abstract semantic, this is the *actual semantic*. 5.1.2.3-6 states what is required to be a conforming implementation:

> The least requirements on a conforming implementation are:
>
> — Accesses to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine.
>
> — At program termination, all data written into files shall be identical to the result that execution of the program according to the abstract semantics would have produced.
>
> — The input and output dynamics of interactive devices shall take place as specified in 7.21.3. The intent of these requirements is that unbuffered or line-buffered output appear as soon as possible, to ensure that prompting messages actually appear prior to a program waiting for input.
>
> This is the *observable behavior* of the program.